# How to give Python full permissions to files windows

Tags: python, permissions, windows-10

I want to make a very basic backup system on my Windows 10 computer. It copies and zips the files in several, predefined places (i can add/remove them through a .json) on my computer into a central backup storage. One thing I would like to back up is Minecraft.
So, I try

```
shutil.copy(r'C:\path\to\minecraft\.minecraft\saves', r'C:\path\to\backups\Minecraft\Saves.zip)
```

The problem is, even when run as admin, it gives a permissions-denied error. Is there any way to give Python permissions to all files, or even just specific folders?

EDIT:

Found out that I was using shutil.copy wrong, and the permissions error was just masking the fact that cannot copy directories. Copying with shutil.copytree works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple fix I found out: *use the right functions*. `shutil.copytree(source, destination)` works like a charm for directories, and `shutil.copy(source, destination)` works just fine for individual files. Hope this helps others in a similar boat!